# Will 'apt-file update' download files of large size?

Tags: apt

I feel like to run `apt-file update`, because

```
$ sudo apt-file search sensors.h
E: The cache is empty. You need to run 'apt-file update' first.
```

But my `/` is almost full, so I wonder if `apt-file update`  will download files of large sizes?

If yes, can I remove them by some commands to free up space once I finish running `apt-file search sensors.h`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what packages sources you are using you should expect at least 30 - 40 MByte to be used.

If you run `apt-file update` as normal user instead of root the files will be downloaded into `$HOME/.cache/apt-file/`. Of course in that case you need to run `apt-file search` as that user, too.

You can use `apt-file purge` to delete the files downloaded by `apt-file update`.

If you just need it once it may be easier to use `Search the contents of packages` at http://packages.ubuntu.com/